# Marklogic Serialization bug in CSV output while converting from SPARQL response

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I'm trying to convert SPARQL output of Optic query to a CSV using this method. I get the response in CSV format, however the column headers repeat after each row for as many rows present in the SPARQL output. How do I correct it?

```
xdmp:set-response-output-method("sparql-results-csv"),
op:from-view("some-tde-view")
=> op:result()
```

Comment: Please work with MarkLogic Support to investigate whether this probable bug.